# Using AWK with multiple delimiters

Tags: linux, awk, cut

I'm trying to get the first part of Column $1 with the entire Column $2,$3 and $5 but unfortunately I'm getting a different output

Input:

```
2023-08-01 05:30:01,Lakers,CA,LA,US
2023-10-05 16:40:23,Denver Nuggets,CO,DN,US
2024-01-20 16:40:23,Utah Jazz,UT,SLC,US
```

Expected output

> 2023-08-01,Lakers,CA,US

```
cut -d, -f1,2,3,5

awk -F',' '{ print $1,$2,$3,$5 }'
```

Comment: That's not `awk`.  `cut` only uses one delimiter.  Have you tried `awk`?

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Only showing 1 line of expected output and that line being the least useful one for demonstrating your requirements since it doesn't contain white space in the team name is not useful.

Comment: That's why different answers are showing different output as we're guessing at your requirements and have nothing except that first sunny-day line to check our output against so see if we got it right or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you want, using any awk, but without expected output in the question it's a guess:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/ [^,]+/,""); print $1, $2, $3, $5}' file
2023-08-01,Lakers,CA,US
2023-10-05,Denver Nuggets,CO,US
2024-01-20,Utah Jazz,UT,US
```

Comment: yes! this match the expected output, can you explain {sub(/ [^,]+/,"")?

Comment: @Driven - what do you think it does? You're almost certainly correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ sub(/ .*/,"",$1); print $1,$2,$3,$5 }' FS=, OFS=, input
```

- set input and output field separators to both be comma
- strip space and trailing from field 1
- print the relevant fields

Comment: or `awk '{ split($1,a,/ /); print a[1],$2,$3,$5 }' FS=, OFS=, input`

Answer (score 0):

`$1` appears to be a timestamp formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. If you want `$1` to only contain the date part, you could use `substr` to extract the first 10 characters only:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print substr($1,1,10),$2,$3,$5}'
```

```
2023-08-01,Lakers,CA,US
2023-10-05,Denver Nuggets,CO,US
2024-01-20,Utah Jazz,UT,US
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `cut` you might get desired output following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
2023-08-01 05:30:01,Lakers,CA,LA,US
2023-10-05 16:40:23,Denver Nuggets,CO,DN,US
2024-01-20 16:40:23,Utah Jazz,UT,SLC,US
```

then

```
cut --bytes=1-10,20- file.txt | cut --delimiter=, --fields=1,2,3,5
```

gives output

```
2023-08-01,Lakers,CA,US
2023-10-05,Denver Nuggets,CO,US
2024-01-20,Utah Jazz,UT,US
```

Explanation: As your timestamp is in fixed-width format it is possible to remove hour-minute-seconds parts by instructing `cut` to take certain ranges of characters - from 1 to 10 (date) and from 20 to end (first `,` and following characters) then use `cut` again to get desired column sheared by `,`. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes your dealing solely with ASCII-encoded files.